# In a C# app, what is the most optimal way to insert many records into sql server?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to perform a very large sql server insert from a c# application.  Somewhere in the range of 20,000 through 50,000 records.

What is the ***fastest*** way through SQL server to perform the insert?

There are several options I know of, but I don't know which is the fastest.

```
   insert into MyTable(column1, column2, ..., column*)
   select 'value','value',...,'value'
   union
   select 'value','value',...,'value'
```

OR

```
   insert into MyTable(column1, column2, ..., column*)
   exec('select ''value'',''value'',...,''value'''
        'select ''value'',''value'',...,''value''')
```

OR

```
   bulk insert from a data file
```

OR

```
   Any better way that you know of :)
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out and tell us about your findings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C#, you can use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), but for raw speed overall, I expect you can get faster with bcp and you can really tune SSIS the most.  In both those cases, you would effectively be using external executables - bcp or dtexec.

Comment: A sentence in the linked documentation really says it all (and implies it's the fastest *managed* way to do it):  There are other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements, for example), but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance advantage over them

Comment: If you can use bcp directly from a text file, it's definitely faster; if the data is already in memory, then `SqlBulkCopy` goes straight over the pipe so it's very efficient. It actually uses the undocumented `INSERT BULK` (**not** `BULK INSERT`) statement and writes directly to the TDS stream.

Answer (score 4):

using SqlBulkCopy class is your best bet if you are going to use C# for bulk copying. I have used it to transfer 15K rows of data and it finishes off in a flash.

HTH

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is probably the best bet.

Comment: Agreement here, I use it to regularly load .5 million records and it flys